# Why can't log in vps with ssh after adding a new sftp user?

Tags: ssh, sftp

The publickey file is on my vps,and private key file is on my local pc.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in my vps:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Every time I can log in my vps with `private key`:

```
ssh root@$vps_ip
```

Today I installed a new user for sftp:

```
groupadd sftp
useradd -g sftp -d /sftp -s /sbin/nologin ipcamera
mkdir -p /sftp/ipcamera/files

chmod 500 /sftp 
chmod 700 /sftp/ipcamera/files
chown root:sftp /sftp/ipcamera
chown ipcamera:sftp /sftp/ipcamera/files
echo "ipcamera:w+w_w+w" | chpasswd

vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowGroups ssh sftp
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication  yes
```

To restart my sshd in vps

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Then I can log in sftp with user `ipcamera` and its password  `w+w_w+w`.

```
sftp  ipcamera@$vps_ip
```

Strange thing happens that I can't log in the vps with ssh command!

```
ssh  root@$vps_ip 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why can't log in vps with ssh after adding a new sftp user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that 'root' is not allowed to log in because it **isn't a member of any group in AllowGroups**. You have added `AllowGroups ssh sftp` to the configuration, but forgot to add 'root' into the 'ssh' group.

Use your VPS provider's "Console access" or "Rescue shell" function to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'root' into the 'ssh' group.

```
usermod -aG ssh root
```